# Get DataFrame selection's row posititions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Instead of the indices, I'd like to obtain the row positions, so I can use the result later using `df.iloc(row_positions)`.

This is the example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['a', 'b', 'c']}, index=[10, 2, 7])
print df[df['a']>=2].index
# Int64Index([2, 7], dtype='int64')
# How do I convert the index list [2, 7] to [1, 2] (the row position)
# I managed to do this for 1 index element, but how can I do this for the entire selection/index list?
df.index.get_loc(2)
```

**Update**

I could use a list comprehension to apply the selected result on the `get_loc` function, but perhaps there's some Pandas-built-in function.

Comment: Why do you want to get the rows, when you can always say `pos = df['a']>=2` and then use that later like `df[pos]`? I guess something like `np.arange(len(df))[pos.values]` is not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `where` from `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['a', 'b', 'c']}, index=[10, 2, 7])

np.where( df.a>=2)
```

returns row indices:

```
(array([1, 2], dtype=int64),)
```

Answer (score 0):

@ssm's answer is what I would normally use. However to answer your specific query of how to select multiple rows try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['a', 'b', 'c']}, index=[10, 2, 7])
indices = df[df['a']>=2].index
print df.ix[indices]
```

More information on `.ix` indexing scheme is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing)

[EDIT to answer the specific query]

> ## How do I convert the index list [2, 7] to [1, 2] (the row position)

```
df[df['a']>=2].reset_index().index
```